# Display members and Value members

Tags: vb.net, combobox, valuemember

Hi I am new to VB platform, Can any one help me to understand the last few lines of code, here I highlight with **bold** at last, which is not understand or confusing to me. What does that Display member and value number do?

.. **cmbcust** is the combobox...

Where **customer** table are having following field.

```
**Customer_sname** **Customer_code** **Customer_fname**
nokia       1       nokia corp.
samsung     2       samsung corp.
sony        3       sony corp.
Micromax    4       Micromax India corp.
```

passing **custval is nokia, samsung, sony**

```
Public Function customfunc(ByVal custval As String) As DataSet
        Try
            Dim strSQL As String = "select * from customer  where  cust_sname  in (" & custval & ")"
            If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Conn.Close()
            Conn.Open()
            Dim Adap As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, Conn)
            Dim Ds As New DataSet
            Adap.Fill(Ds, "customer")
            ReadINICustomers = Ds
        Catch EXP As Exception
            MsgBox("Error Connecting to Server :" & EXP.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Function


   Public Sub Fillcustomer()
        Dim Lstcust() As String
        Dim Lstcust1 As String
        Lstcust1 = ""
        Lstcust1 = custINIval
        Dim Ds As New DataSet
        Ds = objData.ReadINICustomers(Lstcust1)
        cmbcust.DataSource = Ds.Tables("customer")
        cmbcust.DisplayMember = Ds.Tables("customer").Columns.Item("cust_sname").ToString().Trim()
        cmbcust.ValueMember = Ds.Tables("customer").Columns.Item("cust_code").ToString().Trim()
    End Sub
```

**cmbcust.DisplayMember =
Ds.Tables("customer").Columns.Item("cust_sname").ToString().Trim()
cmbcust.ValueMember = Ds.Tables("customer").Columns.Item("cust_code").ToString().Trim()**

Comment: The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) are pretty clear.  The ValueMember is the actual value of the items in the control whereas the DisplayMember is what is shown in the UI.

Comment: If someone picked `sony` the `ValueMember` would return 3.

Comment: Note that your Function name is `funcion` which is a reserved word in VB.Net. You can't use [KeyWords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as a name of something. It should cause a compiler error as well.

Comment: @Eminem if you are going to point out a user on their mistake at least get it right when you point it out :) it should be `function` **NOT** `funcion`...

Comment: @Eminem, I just renamed for posting in stackoverflow from my main source.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Thanks for the link you have provided.

Comment: @OneFineDay short and sweet explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working in any of the .NET languages, such as VB.NET, [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us) is your friend.  It is the official resource for documentation regarding the languages and all of the types in the .NET Framework.  In this case, you are asking about a couple of properties on the `ComboBox` control.  The first thing you should do, then, is to search the MSDN for the `ComboBox` class.  If you do so, you will find [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx).  It lists all of the members of the class and has a separate article explaining each one.  If you scroll down through the list of properties, you will find links to articles for the [`DisplayMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx) property and the [`ValueMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

As those articles describe, the `ComboBox` control can contain any type of objects in its list of items.  If you put something simple like a list of strings into the `ComboBox`, then its obviously easy for it to determine what to display in the list and what to return for its current value.  However, when you place complex custom objects in the `ComboBox`, it's a more difficult proposition.

By default, it will display whatever the `ToString` method returns for each of the objects in its list.  However, by setting the `DisplayMember` property, you can instruct it to use a particular member (such as a `Property` or `Function`) of the objects in the list instead of the `ToString` method.  You do so by setting the `DisplayMember` property to the string name of the objects' member.  It then uses [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) to find the member by that name in each of the objects and retrieve its value.

The `ValueMember` is very similar, but rather than controlling what gets displayed, it controls what gets returned by the `SelectedValue` property.  By default, the `SelectedValue` property simply returns the entire object that was selected in the list.  However, by setting the `ValueMember`, you can instruct it to just return the value of one particular member from the object rather than the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks Steven, From now I will refer MSDN for any .net framework doubts.